# Page that’s used for a single record

Tags: php, bolt-cms

I was just going through the documentation of boltCMS **[HERE](https://docs.bolt.cm/content-in-templates#single-record-pages)**, and came across the following explanation:

> In a page that’s used for a single record, (like entry.twig or
>   record.twig), the variable {{ record }} will always be available,
>   regardless of the contenttype. To make the templates more ‘semantic’,
>   there’s also a variable with the singular name of the contenttype
>   available, like {{ page }}, {{ entry }} or {{ event }}.

I am not quite understanding the below statement 100%:

> In a page that’s used for a single record.

What does the above statement really mean ?

Comment: This seems like a good question to ask [on their discussion forums](https://discuss.bolt.cm/).

Answer (score 2):

In Bolt there's generally two types of pages, listing pages and record pages.

A listing page will show an overview of the items in that contenttype, so `/entries` may show the 10 most recent blog entries with a pager at the bottom.

On a listing page, the variable available in twig is called `records` a listing page will loop over all records and show a summary

```
{% for record in records %}
    {{ record.title }}
    ......etc.....
{% endfor %}
```

On a single record page, eg after you click through to read the full entry `/entry/an-example-entry` then this will be rendered via a record page and a single item (rather than an interable array of items) will be available, you access that using `record` for example the title: `{{ record.title }}`

Hopefully that makes a bit more sense.